# Call a PHP file from Cronjob

Tags: cron

I'm using the MEC Events Calendar. I am trying to auto sync my events to Google Calendar.

Here is what the event plugin says:

> Important Note: Set a cronjob to call
>   /www/wp-content/plugins/modern-events-calendar/app/crons/g-export.php
>   file at least once per day otherwise it won't export your website
>   events into Google Calendar.

First off, I'm not sure how to do this? I installed the WP Crontrol plugin. With this I can add a PHP Cron Event. I am not sure what code I need to put in here to call it?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to first explore your current hosting environment for the possibilities of Cronjobs. It might be called "Scheduled Tasks" or similar.

Alternatively you can schedule a task from within WordPress via [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) (though if you're using the default WP Cron, you can't be certain of it running at the specified time) and load that file via

```
require WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins/modern-events-calendar/app/crons/g-export.php';
```